# How to Import in sass from another directory

Tags: css, sass

I am using "live reload" software to compile my .scss file to .css.

My style.scss file is placed in root directory while I have other files that I want to include into my style.scss and they are placed in root/scss/_author.scss

I tried importing the _author.scss like this but didnt work:

```
@import "../scss/_author";
@import "/scss/_author";
```

Any advise is greatly appreciated as always :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the underscore and the leading slash:

```
@import "scss/author";
```

Comment: Removing the underscore doesn't change anything.